# How to pass parameter from ActionResult to JsonResult?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How can I pass the Id parameter(I already pass in the Id parameter) from ActionResult to JsonResult? Because now I cannot pass in the Id data to JsonResult parameter, so it cannot hit the following JsonResult code.

I using angularjs to display the List of table.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ManageCustomerStocks(Int64 Id)
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetStocksByCustomerId(Int64 Id)
{
   List<CustomerStocksVM> model = new List<CustomerStocksVM>();
   var stocks = _repositories.GetStocksByClientProfileId(Id);

   var result = from stock in stocks
               select new StocksVM()
               {
                   Code = stock.Code,
                    Name = stock.Name
               };

    model = result.ToList();

    return Json(new
    {
        customerstocks = model
    },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.sortBy = function (propertyName) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.propertyName === propertyName) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
    };

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'GetStocksByCustomer'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.customerstocks = response.data.customerstocks ;

    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: You can use viewmodel for `HttpGet` method containing `Id` as `long` property with `return View(viewModel)`, then do like this assuming `@model ViewModel` is set: `var id = '@Model.Id'; $http({ method: 'POST', url: '@Url.Action(...)', data: $.param({ Id: id })).then(...);`

Comment: http.post is compatible with [HttpGet]?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $http({
        url: 'request-url',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'id' : urId }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
    }, 
    function(response) { // optional
            // failed
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to GET something from the backend, use http.get instead:

javascript:

```
 function  GetStocksByCustomerId(id) {
    return $http.get("GetStocksByCustomer", { params: { "id": 
   id} })
   .then(function (response) {
       return response.data
    }) 
    .catch();
}
```

Set your http calls in an angular service